# How do I season wood on my own?

Tags: wood

Just what the title asks. Earlier today a tree on our premises split in two in heavy winds. The tree is of a variety referenced 'सागवन' in the vernacular, and Central Provinces Teak else-wise - that it topped itself is extremely surprising, and uncommon!

After trimming the foliage, and off-shoots I hope to season it. After taking a quick gander at the various notes on seasoning posted online, here's what I find myself wondering

- Is wood seasoned with, or without the bark?
- Should I simply leave the log lying on the ground? It is a fairly hard kind, and the fallen length (approx. 50 ft) far too heavy to lift.
- Need I take any precautions against warp/split?

p.s. I'm told grand-dad seasoned wood letting it lie up-to 10 years thus!

Comment: You want it for making stuff with or for firewood?

Comment: If it's teak, I sure hope it's not for firewood! :)

Comment: Had to ask... you never know, but I should have read more carefully

Comment: @Jack - Sad fact, we burnt Luan Mahogany out of Southeast Asia for several decades. The plywood plant where my father worked imported the veneer and the stickers used to bundle it were reject leftovers either given away to the employees or burnt in the boiler furnace. We got it by the truckload, used what we could and burnt the rest. I have some of another type that's a kind of dense Ironwood like material that I use as a kindling chopping block.

Comment: @Jack Not fire-wood (+: If it ever becomes fire-wood, let it be my pyre

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with Walnut, etc.

You slab it with the bark on, oversize so there is excess stock to work with when planed to final dimension and stack the flitches with stickers between them to keep them separated. The base they're stacked on needs to be flat, the storage sheltered from rain and extremes of weather.

Paint the end grain to slow down moisture movement in aid of reducing checking and minimizing splitting.

When properly dried out, the flitches get resawn and then sent to the planer for finished dimension or sent to the veneer mill to be sliced down into sheets.

A local business, Wagner Electronics, produces moisture meters that are used to determine when wood is seasoned to the proper moisture content. Slow is good. Note: not an affiliate of any kind with the company, just relating how the professionals determine seasoning speed and finish.

Flitch: a piece of wood that is to be resawn or sliced for veneer.

Sticker: thin pieces of wood used to separate flitches or veneer stacks.

Comment: Any recommendations on what to paint the end with?

Comment: Anything that plugs the pores. Thick white exterior latex. You want to prevent water transport in and out of the wood via the way it normally flows so the ends don't dry out faster than the middle.

Answer (score 1):

*सागवन* in Marathi [translates to Sāgavana which is a Hindi word for *teak*](http://www.marathi.indiandictionaries.com/meaning.php?id=58219&lang=Marathi).  This is a common wood in the tropics, uncommon in the subtropics, and rare to nonexistent in temperate and colder areas.

If it is dried (which is what *seasoning* means) slowly, it is less likely to warp and split.  This would be ideal for woodworking uses such as making decking, furniture, etc.  Cut the log into suitable lengths (3–5 meters), raise them off the ground and leave the bark intact.  In a warm, dry climate, they should season in less than two years; for humid climates, it could take 2–5 years.

If the wood is to be used as firewood, cut it up and split it into convenient burnable pieces and stack them off wet ground.  Protecting the stacks from moisture—rain, condensation, etc.—is usually enough for them to burn cleanly in 9 to 12 months, even if there is frequent high humidity.

Comment: I'm curious. Any particular reason to reduce it's length before seasoning (other than the fact that 50ft is plain unwieldly)?

Comment: @Everyone:  more exposed surfaces help speed up drying, besides making it easier to move and better for stacking and storage.